# Alias not assigned correctly

Tags: linux, bash, shell, alias

I have a weird issue with a bash alias. I have the following alias defined in my .bashrc:

```
alias rec='nano `ls slurm-* | sort -t. -k3n | tail -1`'
```

However, when I expand the alias `rec` in the shell with `CTRL` `ALT` `E` I get:

```
nano Remember that all constraints must be readded!
```

If I execute the alias, I get the same thing:

```
nano Remember that all constraints must be readded!
```

If I use `which rec` I get the correct expansion:

```
alias rec='nano `ls slurm-* | sort -t. -k3n | tail -1`'
/home/spack/opt/spack/linux-rhel6-x86_64/gcc-4.4.7/nano-2.6.3-k2cwz7lwjd4zutb7r7cfo63apevyztuw/bin/nano
/home/spack/opt/spack/linux-rhel6-x86_64/gcc-4.4.7/coreutils-8.26-icpocuezd6r7ydd73ipkehkg345372eo/bin/sort
/home/spack/opt/spack/linux-rhel6-x86_64/gcc-4.4.7/coreutils-8.26-icpocuezd6r7ydd73ipkehkg345372eo/bin/tail
```

This `Remember that all constraints must be readded!` is the output of a (supposedly) completely unrelated script that I have written. Any idea what's going on here?

Comment: Pretty much any time you try to do something complex with an alias and it isn't working out, you should make it a function instead--though here be careful about parsing the output of `ls` as well

Answer (score 1):

You are parsing `ls`, [you shouldn't do this](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). I think it *may* be the source of your problem.

E.g. if at lease one of your `slurm-*` filenames is like:

```
*\nRemember that all constraints must be readded!
```

or

```
*\nRemember that all constraints must be readded!\n*
```

where `\n` is a newline, then `sort` receives more lines than you expect. This filename alone:

```
slurm-0.1.-5\nRemember that all constraints must be readded!
```

will make `sort` receive two lines and then in its output the `Remember …` line will be after the `slurm-…` line. I don't know how your `slurm-*` filenames look like exactly. I'm not even sure this is what really happens. My point is you shouldn't parse the output of `ls`.

---

Another weak fragment is where you don't quote the argument for `nano`. This is probably unrelated to your current problem but keep in mind `nano a b` makes nano edit `a`, then `b`, not `"a b"`.